# Data race with memcpy, undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, multithreading, undefined-behavior

I write to an area of memory (with `memcpy`) in one thread, and copy it to a new location with `memcpy` in another. Sometimes these operations can overlap, resulting in a data race. Programs with data races invoke undefined behavior and are invalid.

In this case I check after the copy that the data copied was valid (that no race actually occurred.) If a race did occur, I discard the copied data. However, AFAIK, that doesn't let me off the hook regarding the UB. I think it's still UB whether or not I use the result of the data race.

Now I could write my own `memcpy` routine in assembly (or just copy and paste the one from libc), which would side step the whole UB issue. Assembly is not C++ and whatever happens in assembly won't give the compiler license to invoke the nasal demons<sup>[1]</sup>. Incidentally is that true for inline asm as well as externally compiled and linked asm? Although `memcpy` is already assembly in any modern libc, it can also be treated specially by the compiler, which often does optimizations like a small inline `memcpy` for known sizes and alignments - which may invoke the nasal demons again.

Am I overthinking things here? It's hard to imagine a compiler so god-like that it can detect a data race at compile time - and at the same time so stupid that the optimizer uses it to generate bad code instead of reporting it. But compilers lately have a way of pushing both of those limits - so I feel the need to seek advice here on Stack Overflow.

[Edit] Since there is a lot of curiosity about how I'm synchronizing things here let me explain. The pointer to the memory being copied is shared between threads. It's accessed with atomic `load(mo_acquire)`. Then the memory is copied to a new location. Then there's a `LoadLoad barrier`, followed by a second  `load(mo_relaxed)` of the pointer. If the pointers don't match, the result of the copy is discarded because another thread *may* have raced with this thread during the copy. The thread that writes to the memory first updates the pointer to null with atomic `store(mo_relaxed)` followed by a `StoreStore barrier` and the racing memcpy. So while the two calls to `memcpy` in different threads could be a data race - in reality that's always detected and the result always discarded in that case. I call this scheme copy-on-read and I use it to allow resurrecting objects in a cache after they've been evicted but before the memory has been re-used without any mutexes or "strong" synchronization involved.

[1]: I long for a more civilized time when compilers report UB instead of abusing it for optimizations that may be contrary to the behavior the programmer expects.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are letting a data race occur? Did you consider using locking and/or signaling to enforce the order of execution between threads?

Comment: you have to use some form of synchronization/barrier/atomic no matter what programming language you use otherwise you will get cache coherence, and execution order issues. So just use the ones that c++ supports

Comment: Data races in multithreaded programs is *exceptionally difficult* to detect, and even harder to detect at compile-time.  If you want to work in a "more civilized" time you can switch to a language with a more sophisticated type system which is capable of preventing these errors.

Comment: Also, while there are some forms of UB that compiler can know about and should report (and I agree that compilers often don't seem to do a great job here), the kind of UB that you're describing (multiple threads writing to the same buffer concurrently) can be very difficult to detect at compile time.  I think that even dedicated static analyzer products designed to ferret out runtime problems might often have trouble with detecting that scenario.

Comment: @DietrichEpp and Michael You missed the point. I'm not complaining that the compiler can't detect a data-race (which I agree would be hard!) I don't want them to detect that I have a data race and my program is UB. I'm complaining that compilers do detect UB (like signed overflow) and use that for aggressive optimizations that break real-world (but undefined) programs. Ideally they would warn you instead.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about an issue completely separate from the one you're asking about.  Or do think that `memcpy()` or compiler optimizations have something to do with the data race?  They don't.  The problem with data races is that you're not only working against the compiler's optimizer, but the *processor's* optimization capabilities.  Data races will still give unexpected results in assembly language, even without invoking undefined behavior.  You actually need to synchronize memory access between threads.  Some languages let you enforce this with the type system, but not C++.

Comment: @DietrichEpp from the point of view of the processor and the program as written - this data race is safe. From the point of view of the compiler it's a data race - all data races are UB - so the program is UB and it could conceivably make demons fly out of my nose just to spite me for trying to be clever.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a simplified version of STM.  It is technically UB, there is no way around that.  However, OS developers would probably get out their pitchforks if compilers did anything really bad here.  As long as you are using your memory barriers and atomic operations correctly, it is probably fine.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: OS developers routinely have to disable optimization, because some compiler writers have no interest in making their optimizers suitable for systems-programming tasks which, by their nature, require semantics beyond what the Standard would mandate for compilers that aren't used for such purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronization locks use a very similar method to what you are doing, although only on very small amounts of memory.  A synchronization lock will be faster if the rate of data-race occurence is high, but your approach may actually be faster if the race rate is low.

Although the result of the memcpy is undefined, this is not undefined behavior, as long as you can detect whether a race occurred, and know whether to ignore the garbage results.

This doesn't sound as though you run the risk of a protection violation or similar crash bug; I have not worked with memcpy enough to know if there are any scenarios where it could crash during overlapping operations, but I don't believe it should.

So, as long as the behavior can be detected, this is not necessarily a bad thing, if it meets your needs in a way that is significantly better than standard approaches.  I wouldn't recommend using this "just because", but if you need speed that you can't get with traditional locks, and you document the well-defined-but-non-standard behavior very thoroughly in whatever way you normally provide documentation for maintenance, it is acceptable.

As for the compiler optimization comments, I have never seen a compiler rely on undefined behavior to optimize code, and since C++ compilers are required to guarantee specific behavior according to the C++ spec, I would immediately discontinue using any compiler that relies on undefined behavior for that purpose.  Library code specifically documents that simultaneous read/write operations across threads are not supported and shouldn't be done, so using library code across threads in this way doesn't qualify as undefined behavior, but rather intentional misuse of the library code at your own risk, and all express or implied warranties are void.

Comment: There have been documented cases of compilers detecting undefined behavior and using it to produce completely unintuitive outcomes. I don't believe any nasal demons have been detected yet, but I wouldn't rule it out. I only wish I could remember a link to a specific instance for you.

Comment: Mark is correct, there's a lot of talk about compiler's optimizing UB. Signed overflow is a common case - e.g. compilers optimize `x +1 < x` to false, because it's UB, even although that's quite valid on any two's complement architecture. This has given rise to the discussions of making a friendly C dialect without all the UB so that compilers can't break existing software that's been working fine for decades. AFAIK GCC is the worst offender, but clang plans to follow suite.

Comment: By the way that x+1 < x trick was a common and portable way of detecting signed overflow. However, GCC people (in a regretable fit of stupidity in my opinion) decided since signed overflow is UB, programs that use that to detect signed overflow are UB and it can safely optimize away the check and the error handling code as dead code!

Comment: @Eloff: IMHO, anyone wanting to use that technique even on a compilers that's known to support it should write the expression as `(int)(x+1) < x` to make the intention apparent to any humans reading it.  Further, on many platforms, even commonplace ones, there will be times when evaluating an expression using a type larger than `int` may be faster than processing it with `int`, and I would not regard it as "astonishing" for a compiler to behave in a fashion consistent with arbitrarily promoting (or not promoting) an `int` to a larger type.

Comment: @supercat x+1 when x is maxint on 2s complement architectures wraps around to minint (and so is less than x). No type promotion takes place. But C defined signed overlfow as UB, even although pretty much every architecture in wide use has the same well defined behavior for it.

Comment: @Eloff: My point is that on some platforms, truncating the result of certain expressions to the size of `int` would make things slower, and allowing implementations to promote things *at their convenience* but keeping behavior otherwise on the rails would offer almost as much of a performance boost as allowing compilers to jump the rails completely.  According to the published Rationale, the authors of the Standard did not expect that commonplace implementations would jump the rails with integer overflow, even if the Standard would allow it.

Answer (score 2):

You are mostly correct. Just because one execution thread sees that the copied data is "valid", it doesn't mean that another execution thread will see the same thing.

In order for other execution threads see the effect of some operation, be it `memcpy`(), or anything else, the other execution threads must be "sequenced" with the operation in question.

That's just a rough, inexact summary. A lot of ink has been spilled on sequencing. It's not a straightforward subject, there are a multitude of options and rules.

But the capsule summary is that the easiest way to implement thread-safe and thread-consistent behavior is to use a mutex to protect the shared region of memory which you are using to pass chunks of data between threads. As long as **each** thread acquires a mutex, before accessing the shared memory area, **for reading or for writing**, then all the threads will be one happy family.

Comment: That's the point really, all threads either see a valid copy or don't. The only behavior that isn't permitted is seeing a potentially invalid (racey) copy as valid - which I prevent through some careful loads and stores on a shared atomic variable.

Comment: But the question here is about UB. Is my program UB? Do I have to use my own asm version of memcpy?

Comment: @Eloff - if your program does not do what needs to be done to properly sequence the memcpy with othet threads, then it's undefined behavior. Replacing memcpy with a hand-rolled version will have no effect unless your version is properly sequenced.

Comment: let me rephrase that. I check for an handle data races just fine (by discarded the potentially invalid result.) The problem is to know what hoops must I jump through so that from the POV of the compiler my program does not invoke UB. Because if the compiler discovers that, all bets about what the program does are off. If the compiler doesn't detect that I break the rules - then my program will work fine.

Comment: How substantial your checks are makes no difference, unless your entire operation is properly sequenced. I don't see how a compiler could possibly figure out if you are correctly sequencing your multithreaded code.